# Cannot access system dialogs in Android KIOSK mode

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, cosu

I am trying to connect external fingerprint scanner to the Android application which is in Kiosk mode(Android COSU). 
A system dialog should be displayed to ask for the permissions in order to access the fingerprint scanner. However, In kiosk mode, I cannot see any System dialogs showing up.
Is there a way where I can display system dialogs in Kiosk mode?

Edit: I am able to access Runtime permission dialogs but not Finer print authentication dialog. So, I guess there is some issue only with the USB permission dialog.

Comment: Hi, would it solve your problem if you could grant the permission without showing the dialog at all? If yes then you can try [DevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) or [PermissionGrant](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#PermissionGrant) if you use the Android Management API.

Comment: @Fred: I have used DevicePolicyManager.serPermissionGrantState to assign permission to android.permission.MANAGE_USB. I cannot initialize fingerprint scanner yet as it is still expecting a permission.
Could you please mention what is the exact string for USB Permission?
Do I need to mention Vendor and Product id anywhere?

Comment: The required permission should be in the manifest of the APK requiring it. You can list the permissions used by an APK using `aapt d permissions myapk.apk` (see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/read-apk-permission-by-shell-command)).

Comment: karthikeya koppuravuri, did you resolve the problem? if yes, could you give me the solution, or show the way to solve it?